# spurious dup acks but no lost packets

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

We're seeing the following packets on a single connection.  The client sends 14 inbound data packets.  Then the server sends 1 outbound data packet followed by 14 acks.

The odd thing is that the first 9 acks look more like dup acks.  The ack numbers are not incremented on these 9 packets.  The server suddenly starts incrementing the ack number on packet #25.  And then by packet #29 all 14 inbound packets have been acked.

Does anyone have any ideas on what could cause this?

```
  # |              timestamp        | payload_len | inbound |    seq_num   |  ack_num
----|-------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------+-----------
  1 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883368432 |        1363 |  T      | 2259960578   | 1758954532
  2 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883369602 |         573 |  T      | 2259961941   | 1758954532
  3 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883370622 |        1363 |  T      | 2259962514   | 1758954532
  4 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883372031 |        1363 |  T      | 2259963877   | 1758954532
  5 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883375659 |         652 |  T      | 2259965240   | 1758954532
  6 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883378989 |         573 |  T      | 2259965892   | 1758954532
  7 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883379526 |         257 |  T      | 2259966465   | 1758954532
  8 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883380852 |        1363 |  T      | 2259966722   | 1758954532
  9 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883382081 |        1363 |  T      | 2259968085   | 1758954532
 10 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883383221 |         731 |  T      | 2259969448   | 1758954532
 11 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883383907 |        1363 |  T      | 2259970179   | 1758954532
 12 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883385077 |        1363 |  T      | 2259971542   | 1758954532
 13 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883386306 |        1363 |  T      | 2259972905   | 1758954532
 14 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883387446 |         257 |  T      | 2259974268   | 1758954532
 15 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883460856 |         160 |  F      | 1758954532   | 2259960578
 16 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883464366 |           0 |  F      | 1758954692   | 2259960578
 17 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883468538 |           0 |  F      | 1758954692   | 2259960578
 18 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883472383 |           0 |  F      | 1758954692   | 2259960578
 19 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883475258 |           0 |  F      | 1758954692   | 2259960578
 20 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883477360 |           0 |  F      | 1758954692   | 2259960578
 21 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883478887 |           0 |  F      | 1758954692   | 2259960578
 22 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883480690 |           0 |  F      | 1758954692   | 2259960578
 23 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883483119 |           0 |  F      | 1758954692   | 2259960578
 24 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883485220 |           0 |  F      | 1758954692   | 2259960578
 25 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883492842 |           0 |  F      | 1758954692   | 2259961941
 26 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883496113 |           0 |  F      | 1758954692   | 2259962514
 27 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883497521 |           0 |  F      | 1758954692   | 2259963877
 28 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883498691 |           0 |  F      | 1758954692   | 2259965240
 29 | 2022-07-18 10:40:18.883500911 |           0 |  F      | 1758954692   | 2259974525
```

Also note that no packets were lost or restransmitted.  The server is running linux RH 7.5.

Comment: Likely, the segments (not packets; TCP PDUs are segments, but IP PDUs are packets) are received out of order (TCP handles out-of-order data, presenting it to the application in order). That is not unusual, but neither is it a programming question.

Comment: It's an interesting thought.  The segment listing is from a network tap between our external router and primary switch.  That switch is also directly connected to the internal server.  If the network tap recorded them in the correct order, then my assumption was that the server received them in that order.  Is it possible they were reordered by the switch?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to ask, is there a better place to post questions related to this and not about programming?

Comment: As IP packets traverse a network, they often get dropped or can get out of order. That can happen at any point, including after your tap. TCP is designed to handle that, unlike a connectionless protocol like UDP. There does not seem to be anything wrong. Switches often drop frames due to oversubscription, and lost frames will lose the packets they contain, and that loses the segments contained in the packets. Some TCP variants will resend multiple previous ACKs when receiving a later segment when expecting an earlier segment.